# Getting selected text in active cell from Excel Interop

Tags: c#, vba, excel

I am trying to get the selected text of the active cell in Excel. For instance:

Cell F3 Value:

This is a string.

The user has selected cell F3 and in the formula bar, or directly in the cell, has selected (highlight) 'is a.'

I am interested in getting the selection, 'is a'.

Excel Interop or VBA is acceptable.

[image]

**Update:**

After incorporating some suggestions, I've arrived at the following:

```
    public void SelectionToLowerCase(Excel.Worksheet activeWorksheet)
    {
        activeWorksheet.Application.SendKeys("^c", true);

        var text = Clipboard.GetText();
        var replacement = text.ToLower();
        Clipboard.SetText(replacement);

        activeWorksheet.Application.SendKeys(replacement);

        // potentitally, also:
        // activeWorksheet.Application.SendKeys("^v");
    }
```

This, however, does not work quite right either. The value that is returned from `Clipboard.GetText()` is whatever was in the clipboard before the method was executed. After execution, the clipboard holds the expected value.

My assessment is that Excel's key buffer, which is where the `Application.SendKeys()` method sends its arguments, does not get processed until control returns to Excel.

Is anyone aware of a way to process Excel's keystroke buffer while executing code? `Application.KeyBuffer.Clear()` or some such? (That is not an actual method or property)

Comment: What have I tried? I'm not sure that applies here. I'm asking how to address the API in a specific manner. It's not like I have a particular code or logic issue. I'm not sure what you'd be looking for.

Comment: Well the short answer is no because VBA will not run once you enter edit mode in a cell.  Same with Interop.

Comment: That is patently false. Just tested. Select cell, strike F2, and clicked on one of my own custom ribbon buttons. Code executed, caret is still in the cell.

Comment: If the Excel window is active, `Application.SendKeys "^C"` will work for that.

Comment: @jbarker2160 Is that requesting a copy to clipboard?

Comment: @Michael, Yes.  Then you can paste it somewhere useful (VBA) or get it directly from the clipboard(If you're using C#.)

Answer (score 2):

## Code:

```
Sub GetCopiedText()
    Dim dObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Dim str As String
    
    Application.ActiveWindow.Activate
    Application.SendKeys "^c"
    
    dObj.GetFromClipboard
    
    str = dObj.GetText
End Sub
```

This code will do what you want in VBA, but the trick will be running it.  Excel will not allow the code to execute while the formula bar has focus.
You can click on a custom button and you will not get an error, but the code won't run.

Comment: @Sorceri For clarity: Interop code will run even if the user has entered edit mode. The difficulty at hand is that Excel does not process its keystroke buffer until it gets control back. Important distinction.